# recover the deleted service from windows 2012

Tags: windows

I am using a windows 2012 remote machine. I want to restore the deleted service. Accidentally i deleted a service called "server" from regedit. Is there a way to restore the deleted service back?

Answer (score 1):

## GUI:

Reinstall `File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks` at NIC properties.

Uncheck and check box.

[image: File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks 2012]

## command line:

```
Wmic nicconfig where (InterfaceIndex^>"") get Caption,IPAddress,MACAddress,SettingID
```

as variant may use: `(InterfaceIndex IS NOT NULL)`

or:

```
Wmic nicconfig where (InterfaceIndex^>"") get Caption,IPAddress,SettingID
```

Output:

```
Caption                                                            IPAddress                             SettingID
[00000007] Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 PCI-E Ethernet Controller  {"192.168.20.10", "192.168.103.142"}  {5900BBC4-CAFE-48F1-B6CE-AED224A23CC0}
[00000023] VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter                   {"192.168.56.1"}                      {D71A296D-7BE5-43C1-828B-224464BE0695}
```

Add `File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks` at Atheros NIC.

nvspbind - [Hyper-V Network VSP Bind (nvspbind)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850):

```
nvspbind –e {5900BBC4-CAFE-48F1-B6CE-AED224A23CC0} ms_server
```